# Чи існує слово "будь-деінде"? Якщо так, то як воно пишеться?

Tags: правопис, існування-слова, прислівники

Подумав, що на означення *місць, інших від того, де перебуває суб'єкт*, було би зручно використовувати прислівник "будь-деінде". Наприклад:

> Будь-де_інде мене вже добряче нагодували би, але в цій країні такого звичаю не спостерігалося.

Швидкий пошук показує, що це слово вже [шукали](https://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4486).

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/budj-deinde) і, підозрюю, СУМ-20, який зараз не дуже добре працює, але який можна [приблизно перевірити через пошук](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Aservices.ulif.org.ua%2Fexpl%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5), такого слова не містять.

Одначе маємо 74 результати на запит ["будь-деінде"](https://google.com/search?q="%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5"&start=70) і 185 результатів на запит ["будь-де інде"](https://google.com/search?q="%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5"&start=180) в ґуґлі, а також один результат [будь-деінде](http://parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5&corpname=grac4&corpus-search-form=true) та 3 результати [будь-де інде](http://parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?iquery=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%20%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5&corpname=grac4&corpus-search-form=true) в корпусі ГРАК.

Насправді ж варіантів написання цього прислівника дуже багато:

- будь-деінде
- будь-де інде
- будь де інде
- будь де-інде
- будь-де-інде

Можливо, якісь з них я пропустив. Тож питання: як писати це слово, і чи воно питоме?

UPD. І чи це одне слово?

Comment: Пошуки і приклади тут Ґуґла не дуже надїјні: я не про народниј вжив, а те, же має Ґуґл проблеми з розріжнянӧм врахуваня протинки, можете власноруч прошерстити сторінки — бере шчо з протинкою, шчо без.

Answer (score 7):

> <sub>Правопис 2019</sub>
>
> #### § 41. Прислівники
>
> [1. **Разом** пишемо:](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=44)
>
> 9. прислівники, утворені поєднанням словотворчих часток **аби-, ані-, де-, чи-, що-, як-** зі словом будь-якої частини мови: *аби́куди, аби́як; аніскі́льки, анітеле́нь, анітро́хи, анічичи́рк, анія́к; деда́лі, деі́нде, де́коли, де́куди; чима́ло; щове́чора, щогоди́ни, щода́лі, щоде́нно, щодня́, щоду́ху, щомі́сяця, щомо́га, щонайбі́льше, щонайдо́вше, щонайду́жче, щонайкра́ще, щонайме́нше, щонайши́рше, щоно́чі, щопра́вда, щора́з, щора́зу, щоро́ку, щоси́ли, щохвили́ни* і т. д, *якомо́га, я́кось і яко́сь* (з різними значеннями), *якра́з, якнайбі́льше, якнайду́жче, якнайдóвше* і т. д.
>
> ---
>
> [3. З **дефісом** пишемо:](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=46)
>
> 3. неозначені прислівники, що мають у своєму складі словотворчі частки **будь-, -будь, -небудь, казна-, -то, хтозна-**: *будь-де́, будь-коли́, будь-куди́; коли́-будь, куди́-будь; де-не́будь, коли́-не́будь, куди́-не́будь, як-не́будь; ка́зна-де, ка́зна-коли́; аби́-то, де́сь-то, та́к-то; хто́зна-де, хто́зна-як*;

Тому прислівник має бути **будь-деінде**.

---

> [<sub>Тлумачно-стилістичний словник української мови 2013—</sub>](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5&scope=ukr&main_only=on&dicts=15)
>
> **Будь-деі́нде**, *присл.* В будь-якому іншому місці.
>
> <sup>*На цьому півострові могуття кліру було ще очевиднішим, ніж в будь-якій іншій країні, і клір там більш, ніж будь-деінде, виставляв напоказ своє всесилля і багатство* (Умберто Еко, «Ім’я троянди», переклала Мар’яна Прокопович). *Не мала при такому волоссі веснянок ні на лиці, ні на грудях, чи плечах та спині чи будь-деінде* (часопис «Дзвін»).</sup>
>
> // Усюди, скрізь.
>
> <sup>*Таким чином, ідеології перетворюються в арабському світі на соціальні факти так само, як і будь-деінде* (Роберт Вістріч, «Демонізація іншого: Антисемітизм, расизм і ксенофобія», переклав Г. Краснокутський). *Так що у Франківську дивляться на це абсолютно так само, як і будь-деінде в Україні* (часопис «Український засів»).</sup>

Схожиј вжив

> [<sub>СУМ в 20 книгах</sub>](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/entry/search/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8-%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5)
>
> **Куди́-і́нде**, *присл.* Куди-небудь в інше місце.
>
> <sup>*“А бий тебе сила Божа! – думає Максим. – Хоч би вже повели куди-інде... або ворог де вирискався!.. А то – муштра та й муштра!”* (Панас Мирний); *Розумний чоловік, та ще й козак, куди-інде мірить, а поцілить там, де ніхто того не сподівався* (А. Чайковський); *Як не ховався Дорош, а про хутір знали. Спродатися б та виїхати куди-інде* (Ю. Мушкетик); *Чому вона не переїхала куди-інде, не знаю* (Г. Пагутяк).</sup>

---

**Питоме:**

> [<sub>ЕСУМ Ін-ту мовознавства імя О. О. Потебнї НАН Украӥни</sub>](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5)
>
> псл. *іnъ-de*, утворене від *іnъ* «один, інший» за допомогою частки *-de*, як у псл. *kъde* (рос. *где*) «де»

Для порівняня — [брат](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96): *иноді, иногді*; і [родина](http://sum.in.ua/vkazivnyk/in): *ин(~), инак(~), ино(~)*.

Comment: З одного боку, Ви **абсолютно праві** — я не помітив. З іншого, давно вже хотів сказати, що, по-моєму, варто _трішки_ по-іншому офомлювати посилання (хоча основна причина, через яку я не помітив, — не це, а просто моя неуважність, але це теж трішки сприяло) — пізніше про це напишу.